# Opencart multisite registration strange request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart

I am having a problem that is really stumping me. In my Opencart installation my [account registration page](http://www.moodstar.com/index.php?route=account/register) isn't working. It is a multisite and the page works fine [on the other site](http://www.misticks.com/index.php?route=account/register). The problem is with the zones, when it tries to get zones based on the country it throws an error. When I examined it with Firebug I see that it sends an OPTIONS request instead of a GET request like it does when generating a successful request on the other page.  Unfortunately this isn't the only problem, I was able to get it to send a GET request by specifying "crossDomain: 'false'" as an argument in the .ajax call and that still doesn't fix the error.  The cookies being sent and returned are also different.  I'm trying to find the underlying problem or at least something that will fix the issue.

Edit:
I added responded to questions in a comment as it Stackoverflow did allow me any more links.

2nd Edit:
I've found that the way you access the registration page matters.  Some links to it don't generate any problems.  I'm thinking more and more that this probably has something to do with cookies.

Comment: please add the error you receive to your question. Ideally also show the relevant code...

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be your theme being out of date if it works with one but not the other

Comment: It doesn't give an error code it just says there is an error.  And I am using the same theme as on the site that is working, I think it is some kind of cross domain issue.  The code for the registration page template file is here (http://pastebin.com/PbShuSFc).  The code for the controller is here (http://pastebin.com/HHUhSKNs).

Answer (score 0):

The `OPTIONS` request is indeed very strange in this case and almost looks like the client side (JS/browser) do not know what request methods could be used on the server.

Anyway, in the template `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/account/register.tpl` find this piece of code (almost end of file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('select[name=\'country_id\']').bind('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=account/register/country&country_id=' + this.value,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
```

and before `dataType: 'json',` add `type: 'get',` or `type: 'post',` so You should end up with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('select[name=\'country_id\']').bind('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=account/register/country&country_id=' + this.value,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
```

By this You specify which concrete HTTP request method should be used.